# Dynamically creating complex select objects in a web form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am designing a webform that may capture anywhere from 1 to 150 rows of data giving definitions to what type of data is provided in a given row of a csv.  These rows of data are all exactly same but I do not know how many of them will be used at the outset. I would like to start with one row and let the end user click an add button to add a new row. On the W-3 schools website there was a small tutorial on how to do this:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_select_create
but there are some problems I am seeing.  first, it is buggy.  If you go to the link and click the 'try it' button it will create a simple select dropdown. Wonderful! However, If you click it again it then creates a blank one, with every subsequent click creating the same.  The other problem is that the select element I would need to use is huge (160 possible options) and uses optgroups to keep it separated and intuitive here is a sample:

```
<select name="data_value" id="data_value_selector">
    <optgroup label="Entity Provider">
        <option style="margin-left:12px;" value="name">Name</option>
        <option style="margin-left:12px;" value="dba">DBA</option>
        <option style="margin-left:12px;" value="facility_type">Facility Type</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Individual Provider"></optgroup>
        <optgroup style="margin-left:12px;" label="Name">
            <option value="full_name">Full Name</option>
            <option value="name_prefix">Prefix</option>
            <option value="first_name">First Name</option>
            <option value="middle_name">Middle Name</option>
            <option value="last_name">Last Name</option>
            <option value="name_suffix">Suffix</option>
            <option value="pro_suffix">Professional Suffix</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup style="margin-left:12px;" label="Birth Date">
            <option value="full_birth_date">Full Birth Date</option>
            <option value="day_of_birth">Day Of Birth</option>
            <option value="month_of_birth">Month Of Birth</option>
            <option value="year_of_birth">Year Of Birth</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup style="margin-left:12px;" label="Education">
            <option value="education_institution">Education Institution</option>
            <option value="education_city">Education City</option>
            <option value="education_county">Education County</option>
            <option value="education_state">Education State</option>
            <option value="education_country">Education Country</option>
            <option value="education_start_date">Education Start Date</option>
            <option value="education_end_date">Education End Date</option>
            <option value="graduation_date">Graduation Date</option>
            <option value="degree" >Degree</option>
        </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="Provider Information"></optgroup>
        <optgroup style="margin-left:12px;" label="Address">
            <option value="full_address">Full Address</option>
            <option value="address_1">Address 1</option>
            <option value="address_2">Address 2</option>
            <option value="address_city">City</option>
            <option value="address_county">County</option>
            <option value="address_state">State</option>
            <option value="address_zip_code">Zipcode</option>
            <option value="address_country">Country</option>
            <option value="address_csz">City/State/Zip</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup style="margin-left:12px;" label="Phone">
            <option value="phone_number">Number</option>
            <option value="phone_extension">Extension</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup style="margin-left:12px;" label="Singular Values">
            <option value="url">URL</option>
            <option value="tin">TIN Number</option>
            <option value="email">Email</option>
            <option value="dea_registration_number">DEA Regisration Number</option>
            <option value="npi_number">NPI Number</option>
            <option value="upin_number">UPIN Number</option>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup style="margin-left:12px;" label="Provider Values">
            <option value="provider_value">Provider Value</option>
        </optgroup>
</select>
```

...And this is not even the entire select object.  In the W-3 tutorial it builds each element independently as variables and adds them to each other individually.  As you can see this might take some time to write and just seems very bulky. I would like to define the select object once and have it replicated that way (if possible) with every click.  I imagine each newly created select object would need a unique name, but I am not 100% sure on that.  If that is the case, is there a way to just append a 1 to the name of the first one and so on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want something in jQuery you can use [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) function. See:

```
$("#data_value_selector").clone().appendTo("#select-box");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BtJmA/).

I changed the `name` attribute to send a *collection* of the selected values. You can change this behaviour to a custom name in the click event, if you want:

```
var newSelect = $("#data_value_selector").clone();
newSelect.attr("name", "newName");
newSelect.appendTo("#select-box");
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Awesome!  that jsfiddle is quite handy.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `cloneNode()` method. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JKNT4/7/

HTML

```
<button onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
<div id="parent_selector" class="data-row">
    <select name="data_value[]">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="child_selectors"></div>
```

Javascript

```
 function addRow() {
     var itm = document.getElementById("parent_selector");
     var cln = itm.cloneNode(true);
     cln.removeAttribute("id");
     document.getElementById("child_selectors").appendChild(cln);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks as well.  I assume you guys overlapped in answering.  I like your child_selector div idea, I would like my additions to move downward like the first one does carrying the add button on down with them. so this will get me started on that.  could you use cloneNode to clone the div as well so that the third, fourth and so on behave like the first clone rather than get added on the right?

Comment: @krayzk Yep, you could wrap the select in a styled div and clone that over instead. Edited code above.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks So much!  Your powers combined...  I am Captain Code!

Comment: @Digzol OK So I am pretty satisfied with much of what I have been able to do with your help on this, but I am still having one problem. I would like to rename all of the elements in the child div before I append it. DontVoteMeDown had a way to do this in his solution by using .attr(), but his was cloning just the select, not the whole div. I need a way to access the individual elements in the cloned div. I have come up with a terrible work around where I change the name of the parent, clone it, then change the names back all in the same function... obviously, I want to avoid this if possible.